# Maven depend on JDK javadocs

Tags: java, maven, javadoc

I'd like to depend on the `javadocs` of the JDK in my project. Are there any poms out there that enable this?

(I've had a quick look on maven central but couldn't find anything.)

Comment: The javadocs of the JDK should come with the JDK installation, not from Maven.

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: I'm revising [`JavadocParanamer`](http://paranamer.codehaus.org/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/paranamer/JavadocParanamer.html) and I would like to do the tests against all available output from javadoc across the ages. Depending on the `javadoc` classifier is not so strange.

Comment: If you can't find them as a dependency, available in a remote repository, I guess you could always grab them from your JDK and install in a local repository.

Comment: @Keith it needs to be reproducible on many machines :-( Also, Oracle seem to have dropped the downloads of the original zips.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how feasible it is but What we did in my previous project to quick fix this issue.

We installed maven on a machine and shared its local repository (in the network/LAN) available to other machines either via windows share/ scp / http / jetty server. We then Installed all non standard jars into this repository as one time activity. 
This repository is configured in every systems's settings.xml where maven is to be executed as an additional remote repository.

In the other project where we had more flexibility and time we installed nexus application as a maven proxy. We then created a thirdparty repository to upload custom jars like oracle/sun jars etc not available on maven central.

Comment: thanks... but I'm not looking for ways to host my own Maven repository. I am asking if there is a canonical source of the JDK sources/javadocs via a public maven (it feels like there should be).

Comment: Hmm true, but Unfortunately Until oracle agrees to it, its not gonna happen